# How to rewrite code

Tags: python-3.x

My comment is down below with the code
My program censors words. It works for both one word and many words. I was having trouble making the program work for many words. It would print out the sentence with the space censored too. I found code to make it work though but do not understand it.

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")
word = input("Enter a word to replace:")
words = word
def censorWord(sentence,word):
  # I would like to rewrite this code in a way I can understand and read clearer. 
  return " ".join(["-"*len(item) if item in word else item for item in  sentence.split()]) 

def censorWords(sentence,words):
  words1 = words.split()
  for w in words1:
    if w in sentence:
      return replaceWord(sentence,word)

print(censorWords(sentence,words))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def censorWord (sentence, word):

```
result = [] #list to store the new sentence words
eachword = sentence.split() #splits each word in the sentence and store in a seperate array element
for item in eachword: #iterates the list until last word
    if item == word: #if current list item matches the given word then insert - for length of the word
        item = "-"*len(word)  
    result.append(item)  #add the word to the list
return " ".join(result)  #join all the words in the list with space in between
```

Comment: Ok now I understand! This worked, but I changed '==' to 'in' and 'word' inside len()  to 'item'.

Comment: The 'item' and 'word' would be holding the same value, so they are the same. The == value compares whether both the values are same whereas in keyword check whether word1 is present in word2 even as a part of it. Eg: 'yell' in 'yellow'

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite:

```
s = " ".join(["-" * len(item) if item in word else item for item in sentence.split()])
```

Into:

```
arr = []
for item in sentence.split():
    if item in word:
        arr.append("-" * len(item))
    else:
        arr.append(item)

s = " ".join(arr)
```

It basically splits `sentence` by spacing. Then if the current `item` is in `word`, then it gets replaced with it's own length in hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a bit confused `censorWord()` is censoring all words in the sentence and `censorWords()` looks like it is trying to do the same thing but `return`s in the middle of processing. Just looking at `censorWord()`:

More descriptive variable naming and breaking the one liner down would probably make it clearer, e.g.:

```
def redact(word):
    return '-'*len(word)

def censorWord(sentence, censored_words):
    words = sentence.split()
    return " ".join([redact(word) if word in censored_words else word for word in words])
```

You can always turn this into a `for` loop but list comprehensions are a common part of python and you should get comfortable with them:

```
def censorWord(sentence, censored_words):
    words = sentence.split()
    clean_sentence = []
    for word in words:
        if word in censored_words:
            clean_sentence.append(redact(word))
        else:
            clean_sentence.append(word)

    return " ".join(clean_sentence)
```